# Tinkerpop Blueprints set id/name for graph

Tags: java, graph, graphml, tinkerpop-blueprint

I'm creating some graphs with Blueprints, store them later in GraphML format and want to identify them by an id or name. Does the API provide something like this?

GraphML files (even the ones created by Blueprints) are looking like

```
<graph id="G" edgedefault="directed">
   ...
</graph>
```

So there is an id attribute.

Is there a way to setting this attribute to a Blueprints Graph object and put it to the created GraphML file? Or if not: Is there a better work-around than creating a wrapper class form the graph and the name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this seems to be not possible, because in
[*GraphMLWriter.java*](https://github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints/blob/master/blueprints-core/src/main/java/com/tinkerpop/blueprints/util/io/graphml/GraphMLWriter.java#L198) the ID is hard coded by the constant `GraphMLTokens.G`, which is set to `"G"` in [*GraphMLTokens.java*](https://github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints/blob/master/blueprints-core/src/main/java/com/tinkerpop/blueprints/util/io/graphml/GraphMLTokens.java#L16).